# Position search bar and button on an background image with bootstrap and CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive

I am trying to position the search bar on a background image. I am also trying to position a button at the bottom and center of the image. Following that, I will have containers.

What I am trying to achieve.

[image]

But what I am stuck and confused with positioning. The glyphicon is not working as well?

[image]

My Code

```html
<style>
  .card {
    border: 0px solid;
  }
  
  .drop-shadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgb(211, 211, 211, 0.8);
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
  
  .container-fluid {
    width: auto
  }
  
  .container-fluid.drop-shadow {
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%
  }
  
  .img-fluid {
    height: 200px;
  }
  
  #child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  .btn-checkin {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #fff;
    border-color: #EC008c;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #EC008c;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 0.375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-radius: .25rem;
  }
</style>

</head>

<body id="page-top">

  <div class="card">

    <img class="img-fluid" src="img/1847p.png" alt="Card image cap">

    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="icon-addon addon-lg">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search Class" class="form-control" style="height:30px;position:absolute" id="email">
          <label for="email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" rel="tooltip" title="email"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="child">

      <button class="btn-checkin">Check in</button>

      <div class="container-fluid drop-shadow">
        <div class="row">
          frsjafksdalkdfsa
        </div>
        fsdfdasasd
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

**Problems to target :**

- Get the search bar on the background pic
- Set the background pic always on top of the screen with full width but with certain height. I currently hard coded the height to 200px. Is there a way that it can be responsive?
- I am also stuck with the glyphycon issue, why is it not displayed?
- How do I position the button at the bottom of the image and in the
  center?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of you code with your images & glyphicons import, so i can test easily and give you an answer.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hansheung/2re95qf3/4/

Comment: try my answer below

Comment: responded, you now got all you need and my code is really easy to understand, ask me if needed.

Comment: @rvz, I have problem when the page is displayed on iPad because I set the height to a static 200px. The pic somehow got resized and cut away.  Any way to make the height dynamic?

Comment: setting the width to 100% will adjust the height of the image to keep the resolution of it.

Comment: @robinvrd How do I specify the height of the pic, If I don't specify the height and only width, the pic will not show on the page? Please be more specific, thanks.

Comment: In html, <img> tag auto adjust its dimension to the image file. If you define width property, the image will keep the same ratio and adjust its height to it. If you define height, the image will keep the same ratio and ajust its width to it. If you define both, the image will loose its original ratio. So define only the width !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use margin-top with negative value to make the form goes on the image.
2. Glyphicons look to be working great simply here.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

div#form-box {
  margin-top: -95px;
  
  text-align: center;
}

div#input-group {
  width: 80%;
  
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  
  position: relative;

  background-color: #fff;
  
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


input#email, label[for="email"] {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input#email {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  
  padding: 10px;
  
  border: none;
}

label[for="email"] {
  width: 40px;
  
  line-height: 40px;
}

button#btn-checkin {
  display: inline-block;
  
  padding: 6px 10px;
  
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #EC008c;
  color: #fff;
  
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" />
</head>

<img src="http://wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Desktop-Wallpaper-4.jpg" />

<div id="form-box">
  <form>
    <div id="input-group">
    <label for="email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></label><!--
      --><input type="text" placeholder="Search Class" id="email">
    </div>
    <br/>
    <button id="btn-checkin">Check-in</button>
  </form>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
    .card{
            border:0px solid;
            position:relative;
            height:200px;
            background:url('https://preview.ibb.co/fex0wK/1847p.png') no-repeat top center;
            background-size:cover;
        }
        
        .card img {
          width:100%;
        }
        
        .search-box {
          position : absolute;
          display:inline-block;
          bottom:-30px;
          left:0;
          right:0;
          padding:15px;
          text-align:center;
        }
    
        .drop-shadow {
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgb(211, 211, 211, 0.8);
            border-radius:0px;
        }
        .container-fluid{
            width:auto
        }
        .container-fluid.drop-shadow {
            margin-top:2%;
            margin-left:5%;
            margin-right:5%
    
        }
    
        .img-fluid {
            height: 200px;
        }
    
        #child{
                width:100%;
                height: 20px;
                margin: auto;
                text-align: center;
                margin-top: 40px;
        }
        .form-group {
          width:100%;
          margin-bottom:10px;
        }
        .btn-checkin{
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            white-space: nowrap;
            color: #fff;
            border-color: #EC008c;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            background-color: #EC008c;
            font-family:'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
            padding: 0.375rem .75rem;
            font-size: 13px;
            border-radius: .25rem;
    }
    
    .icon-addon {
      position:relative;
    }
    .icon-addon label {
        position: absolute;
        left: 2px;
        top: 2px;
        padding: 8px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .icon-addon input {
        height:40px;
        padding-left:35px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    
    <body id="page-top">
    
    <div class="card" >
        <!-- <img class="img-fluid" src="img/1847p.png" alt="Card image cap"> -->
        <div class="search-box">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="icon-addon addon-lg">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Class" class="form-control" id="email">
                    <label for="email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" rel="tooltip" title="email"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn-checkin">Check in</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="child">
      <div class="container-fluid drop-shadow">
        <div class="row">
          frsjafksdalkdfsa
        </div>
        fsdfdasasd
      </div>
    </div>
```

Try this code...If you need any help, let me know.

Comment: your code works but when I click on iPad as display. because of the hardcoded height 200px, the pic kinda got cut off? Anyway to rectify this?

Comment: @ Hanz Cheah, you need to increase fixed height when the screen width at 768px (ipad). this happens due to background:cover; style of the banner.It automatically covers the banner area, you have set a fixed height.

Comment: If I set a fixed height to cover iPad, the portrait mode for the rest of the display like iPhone X, S5 will be very tall. Is there a way to change height if say iPad is detected?

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 767px) {
          .card{
            height:335px;
          }
        }  Try this one..This works

Comment: I followed @robinvrd answer and it works dynamically. Thank you for your help, I deeply appreciate.

Comment: @Hanz Cheah, Yep, It's a good answer..but it is not good when the image has large height because banner covers high proportion of device screen.This kind of situation you should apply image as a background image. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you want to position the search bar inside a image.

Make a div with the image as background

```
   background: image_source;
   background-size: contain;
   position: relative; //must to write
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px; //as much as you want
```

Then the css for search bar

```
   position: absolute;
```

then use top, left,etc to position the search bar